# WKWebView don't show Google Map in web page's modal window

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, google-maps

I have a web page and I want to show it in iOS app using WKWebView.
Code of my ViewController.swift:

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
import os.log

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView(){
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated{
            os_log("Link was clicked: %@", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString ?? "")
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

 }
```

All JavaScript on page works fine except Google map, which placed in a modal div and shows on the button tap. So, when I push button to show google map, I see only blank area. It looks like Google Map JS API function "initMap()" doesn't work:

```
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

The map works at browsers and in WebView in Android. I also added "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" in Info.plist and tried to use

```
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

The result is the same
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POL23.png)

Comment: Having the same issue with WKWebview. In my case when I touch the map and move it little bit like 1px then the map appears.

Comment: Getting the same thing in a web app on iOS with Google Maps API. Once you move the [blank] map then it shows up... but it still doesn't show the zoom buttons or the option to switch to satellite imagery. @Mikhail Did you figure out anything on this? - UPDATE: In my case it seems to have to do with some other JS not completing in time.

Comment: @BeninCA I have no other scripts running at the same time with map loading.

Comment: i also found same issue in WKWebView. Has anyone found any solution?

Comment: Excuse me, have you solved it?

Comment: Anyone solved this issues?